# MinGW 64 error in integer (long int) arithmetic

Tags: c++, math, mingw-w64

Hope you can help me; I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

long int
cifra (long int b, long int e, long int n)
{
  /* Calcula a tal que (b^e)=a MOD n. Algoritmo 3.1 de Allenby & Redfern,1989. */
  long int a, i, q, r;

  a = 1;
  q = b / n;
  r = b - q * n;
  for (i = 1; i <= e; i++)
    {
      a = a * r;
      q = a / n;
      a = a - q * n;        /* ou, de forma equivalente, a=mod(a,n) */
    }
  return a;
}

int
main ()
{

  long int a, b, e, n;

  b = 116104101;
  e = 19661;
  n = 383768051;

  a = cifra (b, e, n);

  cout << "a=" << a << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and this should output

a=199324862

as it does when I used the online C++ Compiler (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler, which uses g++).

However: if I run it on Code::Blocks with MinGW64 (on Windows 10), I get the wrong result:

a=298405922

Any ideas? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Avoid `long`. It's the only built-in integral type that doesn't have an estabilished size on common platforms (32 bits on Windows, 64 on most others). Either use `long long`, or `int*_t`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `long` useful with `ftell()`, `.tv_nsec`, a _signed_ version of `size_t`, `strto_some_small_int()`, widest integer for C89 code. Yet agree with the general  mantra that `long` has limited usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

**Overflow**

`q * n`, `a * r`, `q * n` risk overflow.

The width of `long` is at least 32-bit, yet a full range multiplication obliges 2x `long` width for the product.  On some platforms it is 64-bit and thus success with the test values on some, failure on others.

Either:

1. Use a wider type for intermediate calculations.  `long long` would suffice for OP's test case of `b = 116104101; e = 19661; n = 383768051;` yet still fail with `long long` for `b = 116104101<<32; e = 19661<<32; n = 383768051<<32;`

or

2. Perform the math more carefully.  Example: [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485).

---

**Slow**

`for (i = 1; i <= e; i++)` is *very slow* with large `e`.  Research [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

---

**Bug**

`int64_t cifra(int64_t b, int64_t e, int64_t n)` incorrect with some small corner cases.  `cifra(b, 0, 1)` returns 1 when it should return 0.

```
// a = 1;
a = n > 1 ? 1 : 0;
// or 
a = 1%n;
// or ...
```

---

**Sample fix**

Example fix for OP's code with limited range.  I went for *unsigned* types as analyzing    *signed* types with negative values is too tedious right now.

```
uint32_t cifra32(uint32_t b, uint32_t e, uint32_t n) {
  uint64_t a = 1%n;
  uint64_t q = b / n;
  uint64_t r = b - q * n;
  for (uint32_t i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
      a = a * r;
      q = a / n;
      a = a - q * n;
    }
  return a;
}
```

More improvements possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're assuming that `long int` is a 64-bit (or larger) integer type, but it's actually a 32-bit type in that particular environment. If you need a certain size type you should use something more explicit like `int64_t` or `uint64_t`. Also, you might want to use the remainder operator `%` to avoid the `q` variable altogether, e.g. `r = b % n` or just `b %= n`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int64_t cifra(int64_t b, int64_t e, int64_t n) {
    /* Calcula a tal que (b^e)=a MOD n. Algoritmo 3.1 de Allenby & Redfern,1989. */
    int64_t a, i;

    a = 1;
    b %= n;
    for (i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
        a = (a * b) % n;  /* ou, de forma equivalente, a=mod(a,n) */
    }
    return a;
}

int main() {

    int64_t a, b, e, n;

    b = 116104101;
    e = 19661;
    n = 383768051;

    a = cifra(b, e, n);

    std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help!